Powershell script to show role assignment and scope for all accounts in Azure
I have written a powershell script that should show me all role assignments, display name / signin name.
What is the problem with the script.
The scope is incorrect, when you look at the resource group in Azure and download the roe assignment onto a csv file, it is not thesame as what my script is generating, what I want to know is if the role was assigned at the resource group level, inherited at the subscription root level or inherited at the management group level.
Lastly, when reconciling the output of the report with what I can see on the portal,in one case the number of assignment is more on the report when compared to the output on the portal, its not a duplicate it appears to be a role assignment that isnt just there but was getting returned by the powershell script below.
# Define the output file with date and time appended in DDMMYYYY_HHMMSS format
$outputFile = "C:\output\Export-AzRolesGroups_$((Get-Date).ToString('ddMMyyyy_HHmmss')).csv"

# Initialize the result variable
$allRoleAssignments = @()

# Get role assignments at the management group level
$managementGroups = Get-AzManagementGroup
foreach ($mg in $managementGroups) {
    $mgScope = "/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/$($mg.Name)"
    $mgRoleAssignments = Get-AzRoleAssignment -Scope $mgScope -IncludeClassicAdministrators | ForEach-Object {
        $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "TenantId" -Value "" -Force -PassThru |
            Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "SubscriptionName" -Value "" -Force -PassThru |
            Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "SubscriptionId" -Value "" -Force -PassThru |
            Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ResourceGroupName" -Value "" -Force -PassThru |
            Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ManagementGroupName" -Value $mg.Name -Force -PassThru |
            Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Scope" -Value $mgScope -Force -PassThru
    }

    # Add to the result variable
    $allRoleAssignments += $mgRoleAssignments
}

# Get all subscriptions in the tenant
Get-AzSubscription | ForEach-Object {
    # Skip the subscription named "Exclude sub"
    if ($_.Name -eq "Excluded Sub") {
        Write-Verbose -Message "Skipping Subscription $($_.Name)" -Verbose
        return
    }

    Write-Verbose -Message "Changing to Subscription $($_.Name)" -Verbose

    # Set the context to the current subscription
    Set-AzContext -TenantId $_.TenantId -SubscriptionId $_.Id -Force
    
    $Name = $_.Name
    $TenantId = $_.TenantId
    $SubId = $_.Id

    # Get role assignments at the subscription level
    $subscriptionScope = "/subscriptions/$SubId"
    $subscriptionRoleAssignments = Get-AzRoleAssignment -Scope $subscriptionScope -IncludeClassicAdministrators | ForEach-Object {
        $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "TenantId" -Value $TenantId -Force -PassThru |
            Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "SubscriptionName" -Value $Name -Force -PassThru |
            Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "SubscriptionId" -Value $SubId -Force -PassThru |
            Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ResourceGroupName" -Value "" -Force -PassThru |
            Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Scope" -Value $subscriptionScope -Force -PassThru
    }

    # Add to the result variable
    $allRoleAssignments += $subscriptionRoleAssignments

    # Get all resource groups in the subscription
    $resourceGroups = Get-AzResourceGroup

    # Get role assignments at the resource group level
    foreach ($rg in $resourceGroups) {
        $resourceGroupScope = "/subscriptions/$SubId/resourceGroups/$($rg.ResourceGroupName)"
        $resourceGroupRoleAssignments = Get-AzRoleAssignment -ResourceGroupName $rg.ResourceGroupName -IncludeClassicAdministrators | ForEach-Object {
            $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "TenantId" -Value $TenantId -Force -PassThru |
                Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "SubscriptionName" -Value $Name -Force -PassThru |
                Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "SubscriptionId" -Value $SubId -Force -PassThru |
                Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ResourceGroupName" -Value $rg.ResourceGroupName -Force -PassThru |
                Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Scope" -Value $resourceGroupScope -Force -PassThru
        }

        # Add to the result variable
        $allRoleAssignments += $resourceGroupRoleAssignments
    }

    # Process each role assignment
    foreach ($roleAssignment in $subscriptionRoleAssignments) {
        if ($roleAssignment.ObjectType -eq "Group") {
            $group = Get-AzADGroup -ObjectId $roleAssignment.ObjectId
            $groupMembers = $group | Get-AzADGroupMember | Select-Object UserPrincipalName, ObjectType, Id

            foreach ($member in $groupMembers) {
                $member | Select-Object @{Name = "GroupName"; Expression = { $group.DisplayName }}, UserPrincipalName, ObjectType, Id | Format-Table
            }
        } else {
            $roleAssignment | Format-Table
        }
    }
}

# Remove duplicate entries by ObjectId and Scope
#$allRoleAssignments = $allRoleAssignments | Sort-Object ObjectId, Scope -Unique

# Export the results to a CSV file
$allRoleAssignments | Export-Csv -Path $outputFile -NoTypeInformation -Force

Write-Output "Role assignments have been exported to $outputFile"

